# Big O time complexity of n^1.001

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

- Why is the growth of `n^1.001` greater than `n` `log n` in Big O notation?
  The `n^0.001` doesn't seem significant...

Comment: what is 1e62 ^ 1.001 ?   What is 1e62 * log(1e62)?

Answer (score 3):

For any exponent (x) greater than 1, n<sup>x</sup> is *eventually* greater than n * log(n). In the case of x = 1.001, the n in question is unbelievably large. Even if you lower x to 1.01, n<sup>x</sup> doesn't get bigger than n * log(n) until beyond n = 1E+128 (but before you reach 1E+256).

So, for problems where n is less than astronomical, n<sup>1.001</sup> will be less than n * log(n), but you will eventually reach a point where it will be greater.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested, here is a formal proof:

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume we are using logarithms in base `e`.

Let `a > 1` be any exponent (e.g., `a = 1.001`). Then `a-1 > 0`. Now consider the function

```
f(x) = x^(a-1)/log(x)
```

Using L'Hôpital's rule it is not hard to see that this function is unbounded. Moreover, computing the derivative of `f(x)`, one can also see that the function is increasing for `x > exp(1/(a-1))`.

Therefore, there must exist an integer `N` such that, for all `n > N`, is `f(n) > 1`. In other words

```
n^(a-1)/log(n) > 1
```

or

```
n^(a-1) > log(n)
```

so

```
n^a > n log(n).
```

This shows that `O(n^a) >= O(n log(n))`.

But wait a minute. We wanted `>`, not `>=`, right? Fortunately this is easy to see. For instance, in the case `a = 1.001`, we have

```
O(n^1.001) > O(n^1.0001) >= O(n log(n))
```

and we are done.